# Java class with DTD to XML

Tags: java, xml, dtd

actually i have a problem with a exercise from studing, cause i'm preparing for the exam.

i have the classes

```
class Einwohnermeldeamt {
  HashMap<Integer,Wohnung> wohnungsGesamtliste;
  HashMap<Integer,Person> einwohnerGesamtliste;
}

class Wohnung {
  int wohnungsNr;
  String Ort;
  int plz;
  String straße;
  int hausNr;
  ArrayList<Person> bewohnerProWohnungListe;
}

class Person {
  int personNr;
  String vorname;
  String nachname;
  Date geburtsDatum;
  ArrayList<Wohnung> wohnungenProPersonListe;
}
```

Now i have to **write a XML DTD (Document Type Definition)** by hand to map these Informations to save them in a XML file later.

I searched the problem with google, but i can only find the way XML to Class not my way.

Would be nice if someone could explain me, how it works and what the DTD is

Comment: Start by reading about the DTD in the [XML specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-doctype).